# Php function not working ,undefined variable

Tags: php

I getting a php error

> undefined variable $fname

```
 $fname="John";
 function getThis()
 { 
  $complete_name= $fname."Kerry";
echo $complete_name;}
    getThis();
```

Any help in the right direction is   much appriciated! Thanks

Comment: use `global` keyword for `$fname`

Comment: Variable scoping issue most likely

Comment: yes, it's about scoping, I admit it. otherwise, you have other related codes with it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you have a variable scoping issue

> Variables defined outside the function have **Global scope** and they can not be used inside a function, If you want to use them inside a function You must write the **global** keyword before the variable name.
>
> ```
>  global $fname;
> ```

**And in your case**

I noticed that Variable **$fname**  is defined outside the function, and it has a global scope, if you use this inside the function ,then it will throw error.

**Try this**

```
  $fname="John";
  function getThis()
 { global $fname;
  $complete_name= $fname."Kerry";
echo $complete_name;}
    getThis();
```

**Source** :

http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php

Answer (score 1):

Try to place the `$fname` inside the `getThis()` function, as in:

```
<?php

 function getThis() { 
 $fname="John";
 $complete_name= $fname."Kerry";
 echo $complete_name;
 }
 getThis();

?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use This :-

```
$fname="John";

    function getThis()
     { 
    global $fname;
    $complete_name= $fname."Kerry";
    echo $complete_name;
    }
    getThis();
```

[For more information click here](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php)

Answer (score 1):

You could pass the variable into the function.

Like so:

```
 $fname="John";

 function getThis($f_name)
 { 
   $complete_name= $f_name."Kerry";

   echo $complete_name;
 }

 getThis($fname);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can not access variables inside function which declared out side, you have to use global keyword to use....

```
 $fname="John";
 function getThis()
 { 
global $fname;
$complete_name= $fname."Kerry";
echo $complete_name;}
    getThis();
```

Comment: Maybe just add comment as to what was changed and why.

Answer (score -1):

You have to declare $fname as global. That's it...